# Printing a report from selected data (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, printing, web

Say a table is displayed on a website (containing the table data from the mysql database).
For example:

```
   id      Name       Email      X       Date
   0       aaa        aa@a.com   ccc     10 jan 1993
   1        bbb       nn\\.com   fff     20 feb 1994 etc
```

I want to have drop down lists or radio buttons for selecting specifically which data i want to display in a report. (For instance, I want to select the data only from the Date : February 1994 or whatever) 
Then I want to click a button that will print the selected data in a report form.
(I'm mainly interested in the code for the button.)

Can anyone please recommend a good tutorial or maybe a piece of code that will help?

I'm writing this website using PHP and a mysql database.

******EDIT
this is PART of my code for displaying the table on the webpage. So any suggestions?

```
   $table = 'table';

    if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

    if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

    // sending query
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
    if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
    }

    $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

    echo "<h2>Table: Database </h1>";   ?>  
    <input name='Print' type='print' id="print" value='Print'>
    <?php
     echo "<table border='3'><tr>";
    // printing table headers
     for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
     {
      $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
      echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
     }
     echo "</tr>\n";
     // printing table rows
     while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
     {
       echo "<tr>";

     // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
     // of $row to $cell variable
      foreach($row as $cell)
      echo "<td>$cell</td>";

       echo "</tr>\n";
      }
      mysql_free_result($result);
      ?>
```

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: @ankitbajpai All i have is the code to display the table on the webpage. I haven;t done anything yet regarding the question. I'm looking for a tutorial or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say report, are you talking about something like PDF?
If that's the case then I recommend you read about MPDF.
http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

This class will convert your html codes into a PDF report.

For your button just create a form that accepts a date input that you can use to query from the database when you click submit.